# Can You Specify Where LVM Snapshots Are (Initially) Stored?

Tags: backup, lvm, snapshot

Disclaimer: this is my first time using lvm.

Upon RTFM, it appears that LVM snapshots are automatically stored in the same directory as the original logical volume. In my case, that would mean the `/dev` directory. This isn't very nice, because there's not enough disk space in there for me to store a large snapshot.

So when I run a command like `lvcreate --size 1G --snapshot --name snapshot /dev/lvmData/usr`, I need an additional 1G of space free in /dev?

Is there any way to specify a different directory in which to store my snapshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files in `/dev` are not ordinary files - they are devices represented as files.  The LVM-snapshot is a block device, and takes up space from LVM.

The `1G` you specified with `lvcreate` is taken from the `Free` column on the `lvmData` line after you've run the `vgs`-command.

Comment: I see. That - is awesome.

Answer (score 2):

if you have all the space in the VG filled with LV's, you can add a disk to the VG and use it as a snapshot. So next time you create a snapshot, you know that the snapshot must be created in the the new disk.